# Spring Websocket chat multi usuário com som

Tags: html, spring, websocket

Estou tentando desenvolver um chat em tempo real, com o seguinte cenário.

- Atendente online
- Cada usuário que ele atender é uma conversa **Um para UM**
- Um atendente vê todos os usuários em uma lista que ele esta atendendo.
- Quando ele fala, fala somente para um.
- Também poderá optar por falar com todos.
- Poderei ter uma lista de atendentes, cada atendente tem a sua lista.
- Minha lista de atendentes deverão estar logados, para receber usuários em sua lista.
- **Cada mensagem chegada de qualquer lado deve tocar aquele som "pooom" de mensagem chegando**

Alguém tem documentos, sites e projetos com as características abaixo

1. Spring
2. Websocket
3. cliente html

Que oriente nesse sentido e atenda o que preciso ou parte disso?

**Hoje estou com um chat que esta assim, tipo aqueles chat antigo de bate bapo, onde alguém entra e fala com todo mundo tudo ao mesmo tempo, e também esta lendo as mensagens antiga**

Comment: Coloca aqui o código do chat que você tem.

Comment: Tente fazer uma pergunta mais objetiva. Inclua seu código, e descreva o problema que você está enfrentando. Assim fica mais fácil resolver.
A propósito, já conhece o http://tawk.to ?